# Error constructing a generic method in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift2, generic-programming

I'm getting an error when trying to create a generic method.

```
static func sendRequest<T>(method: Alamofire.Method, urlString: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?) -> T {
    let response : T
    Alamofire.request(method, urlString, parameters:parameters)
        .validate()
        .responseObject { (response: Response<T, NSError>) in
             switch response.result {
            case .Success(let value):
                response.valueHandle?(value)
            case .Failure(let error):
                response.errorHandle?(error)
            }
        }
   return response 
}



    var valueHandle :((AnyObject) -> ())?
    var errorHandle :((NSError)->())?

    func success(value:(AnyObject) -> ())->Self{
        self.valueHandle = value
        return self
    }

    func error(error:(NSError)->())->Self{
        self.errorHandle = error
        return self
    }
```

The error is: `Cannot convert value of type '(Response<T, NSError>) -> ()' to expected argument type 'Response<_, NSError> -> Void'`

Is my generic method not constructed properly?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight updated.

Comment: Can you post the code for where you call the generic method? Judging on that error message it could be a parameter issue.

Comment: Can you mark the place in your code where the error message shows up?

Comment: Actually it's fixed. I had to do sendRequest<T:ClassName> instead of just sendRequest<T>. I should probably mark this question for deletion.